# SharePoint 2013- How to report on each site?

Tags: 2013

I am looking for a way to report on discussion board and page usage (how many discussion boards and threads, how many pages are created, so on) for each site, and I am undecided on what approach to take.

Powershell or Farm Solution is not an option as they do not want it unfortunately. There is a single web application and lots of site collections underneath this. Reporting is required per-site collection.

I thought of doing this in a console application that will be a scheduled task and produce reports but  the lack of documentation put me off.

Do you think it's worth doing this as an app/add-in? I have not really been watching where the app model(add-in model) ended. For me it's very easy to do this using client object model/ rest per site, but I can't figure out how to deploy this to each site collection. Can someone at least tell me where to start. I have been to SharePoint Development site, but there are too many new things and they look all for SharePoint online, so I feel a bit lost, on the remote SharePoint On-Premise island..

Answer (score 0):

REST/CSOM based Javascript solution could work in your case. You can store the file in the _layouts directory on your SP server  and reference the file using a script editor webpart on each site collection.

Comment: is this going to be deployed as an app then? because writing the JavaScript is not the issue, it's more of how do I deploy it to all site collections.

Comment: You can add the script editor webpart to a page with CSOM/SSOM using Powershell/Console app. https://www.google.co.uk/?q=add+script+editor+web+part+csom -- http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-Script-Editor-WebParts-to-SharePoint-2013-Publishing-Pages-using-PowerShell

http://blog.csdn.net/tristan_dong/article/details/12052113